# Protobuf3 why repeated map is not allowed?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am using Protobuf3 and I need to create a list of map.
I thought I can use `repeated map<string, string>` but seems like I cannot.

What should I use instead?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Essentially, `map<...>` is identical to:

```
repeated TypedPair ...
```

with

```
message TypedPair {
    KeyType key = 1;
    ValueType value = 2;
}
```

So `repeated map<...>` would be `repeated repeated TypedPair` which doesn't make sense.

Instead, define a type that *has* a map, and use that:

```
message HazMap {
    map<...> map = 1;
}
...
repeated HazMap maps = 1;
```

Could this be implicit? Perhaps - but it isn't right now.

Comment: This is interesting but let say if i expect this field to look like
[ {"somekey" : "someVal"}, {"someKey2": "Otherval"} ]? this HazMap will add a map in between

Comment: @Anthony oh, I see! Yeah, it will add an extra layer : `{"map":{...}}` - can't fix that

Comment: @Anthony ultimately if you want full control of the json: use a json serializer library, not a protobuf library that happens to be able to also talk json as a second tongue

Answer (score 1):

you can use `google.protobuf.ListValue`.

```
import "google/protobuf/struct.proto" // important

message Example {
  google.protobuf.ListValue map_list = 1 [json_name="map_list"];
}
```

in golang, you can initialize by this way.

```
structpb "google.golang.org/protobuf/types/known/structpb"

newStruct, _ := structpb.NewStruct(map[string]interface{}{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
})
newStruct2, _ := structpb.NewStruct(map[string]interface{}{
    "key3": "value3",
    "key4": "value4",
})
...
MapList: &structpb.ListValue{
        Values: []*structpb.Value{
            structpb.NewStructValue(newStruct),
            structpb.NewStructValue(newStruct2),
        },
    },
...
```

json like this

```
"map_list": [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    {
        "key3": "value3",
        "key4": "value4"
    }
],
```

[see here for detail](https://github.com/ethresearch/sharding-p2p-poc/pull/37)